# Different css styling for last element of a php array

Tags: php, css, loops, for-loop

When looping through an array how can I create a different css div style for the last element to be output  in my array.

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($productid);$i++){if($productrank[$i]>0 ){

<? if (($productid[$i] % 2 ) && !( last element of array){ echo '<div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back  vLine " style="width:50%;">';}
else { echo '<div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back " style="width:50%;">';} ?>
```

Comment: fyi, you should never use `<?` but always `<?php` (unless you use the `<?= some_expression ?>` syntax which is always supported)

Comment: you get the last element with `$productid[count($productid)-1]`. your if construct is doing something different though.

Comment: If your last div is the last child of its parent, you could simply use the `:last-child` selector in your CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if it is the last $productid

```
for(...)
{
    if ($i === (count ($productid) - 1))
        // Last one -> special CSS
    }
}
```

Also, DO NOT use `count()` in a FOR loop if you don't really have to.
Just assign a value BEFORE and use it :

```
$count_temp  = count ($productid);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_temp; ++$i)
```

And use this $count_temp again if the IF statement to check if it's the last element

---

Answer to comment :

`How would this same method get the first element?`

```
if ($i === 0)
```

Or

```
// Special CSS for $i = 0
// Start loop at 1 instead of 0
for ($i = 1; $i < $count_temp; ++$i)
```

Comment: That worked for me, one question though... why is it not good to use the count() in the FOR loop?

Comment: Because it will REcount everytime you loop, so if your array has a  length = 100 000, you will run count($array) 100 000 times, instead of 1 time by doing it outside of the loop.

Comment: How would this same method get the first element?

Comment: I edited my answer for the first element, check it out and tell me if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, if you've a new decent question, create a new post and delete these comments. No one can read this in four comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490793/different-css-styling-for-last-element-of-a-php-array-pt-2

Answer (score 1):

You can do this purely with CSS using `:last-child`. It is [supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/) by all modern browsers.

```
div.centerBoxContentsFeatured:last-child {
    /* special styles for last */
}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9y93j/1/

Comment: I tried this in addition to what I had, it worked but not exactly what I need. I can use it in other projects those thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if($productid[$i] ==  $productid[count($productid)-1]){
    //last element code here
} elseif (($productid[$i] % 2 ){
   //even row code here
} else {
   //odd row code here
}
```