# Different css styling for last element of a php array Pt.2

Tags: php, css, arrays

Ok here is my new issue, and a complete description of what I am trying to accomplish.  I used the suggestions you gave me and it worked fine, but when I changed the ORDER by information to a different field and the if statement, it went crazy.

Here is what I need, I have two columns on a page, when the array is processed I need it to display results filling each column left to right top to bottom.  There is a division line between each item

```
<div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back  vLine " style="width:50%;">
```

and one under each item

```
<div class="product-col" >.
```

If the item is the 3rd, 5th, 7th and so on… it will be on the left and does not need the “vLine “ div before it and if it is the last item(s) it does not need the  “product-col” div under it as the last 2 items do not have to have the bottom divider, but if it is only two items on the whole page the bottom divider can stay.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$count_temp  = count ($productid);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_temp; ++$i) {
    $artist = get_the_title();
    if (($productartist[$i] == $artist ) && $categoryID[$i] ==1 ) {
    ?>
//Content//
<?php if (!($i === 0) && !($i % 2)  &&
         ($productid[$i] == 1) &&
         ( $i === (count ($productid) - 1))) {
             echo'<div class="product-col-none" >';
      }
      else  { echo '<div class="product-col" >';} 
?>
//Content//
<? if !( $i === (count ($productid) - 1))
   { 
        echo '<div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back  vLine " '.
             'style="width:50%;">';
   }
   else { 
        echo '<div class="centerBoxContentsFeatured centeredContent back " '.
             'style="width:50%;">';}
?>
```

Comment: please provide a link to the other problem you correspond to.

Comment: let's say to "Pt.1" ... the url would be fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445139/different-css-styling-for-last-element-of-a-php-array

Comment: Well, If my answer is working good on your problem...you can then accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should write here about your css file code, you are making things complicated and unclear with your html embedded php code.

If you just want a different style for your **odd** numbered (3,5,7..) items and a different style for your **last** item then I'll recommend to use **`css pseudo classes`**

You can use css pseudo class last-child for your last item.

```
li:last-child
{
  // Your specific style for last item goes here
}
```

You can also use css pseudo class nth-child(odd) for alternating odd numbered items

```
li:nth-child(odd)
{
  // Your specific style for odd items goes here
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, Why to give a server side load when you can set things done at client end.