# How to change last child with inline style

Tags: css, arrays, email, inline

So i have a element i want to send via email, so its style has to be defined inline. The style is applied to the array of element. I need the last element to be different style is there a way to do it?

```
<div class='label' style=' margin-bottom: 5px; min-height: .75em; width: 8em;
 font-weight:bold;  font-size:1.2em; color:#333; display: inline-block;'>$key:   
</div>
```

Comment: Tell me if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445139/different-css-styling-for-last-element-of-a-php-array#

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using javascript as you said your elements are in an array. Here is how you can access last element and apply style to it:

```
var last = arrayName.length -1;
arrayName[last].style.cssProperty = 'value';
```

Where you have to replace *arrayName* with your array, *cssProperty* with the property you want to change and *value* with the value of property. For example,

```
arrayName[last].style.color='red';
```

Comment: Can't make it work, my document is in php, all the variables are defined with $ and it doesn't understand the function

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

HTML:

```
<div class='label' style=' margin-bottom: 5px; min-height: .75em; width: 8em;
 font-weight:bold;  font-size:1.2em; color:#333;'>  

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.label > * {           
  display: inline-block;
}
div.label > :last-child{
  display: block;
}
```